# Rails undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

The following is my current code. I removed parts not needed to understand the problem.

Setting Model

```
class Setting < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :program_id, :session_types

  def initialize
    @session_types = Array.new
    @program_id = ''
  end
end
```

Setting Controller

```
  def new
    @setting = Setting.new
    puts @setting.session_types.instance_of? Array
  end
```

Setting View

```
<%= form_for(@setting) do |f| %> #ERROR LINE
    ...
<% end %>
```

I get this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
    3: </h1>
    4: <p>We need to get your booking page setup. Please select the Program you wish to put up for booking.</p>
    5: 
    6: <%= form_for(@setting) do |f| %>
    7:     <% @programs.each do |program| %>
    8:         <%= f.radio_button(:program_id, program.program_id)%>
    9:         <%= label_tag(:program_name, program.name) %>
  app/views/settings/new.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_settings_new_html_erb__94314060479739781_70294544827460'
```

`@setting.session_types = Empty Array` when debugging.

So I tried replacing `Setting Model` with a simple `Testing Model` without the array attribute as follows:

```
class Testing < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :program_id
end
```

to see if it is the `Array` attribute `session_types` of `Setting` that is causing the error. It seems so becuase with `Testing`, I get an error in the line AFTER the `form_for` line, which should be correct. (the line is not needed to undestand the problem)

I think I am not understanding the initialization of an `Array` attribute of a model properly. Any help to understand why the error is thrown will be appreciated! Thanks in advance! =D

Comment: Make sure is the `Setting` class you think it is.

Comment: @DaveNewton What do you mean by that? I only have 1 class that is called Setting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
def initialize
  super
  @session_types = Array.new
  @program_id = ''
end
```

You were very scarce with pasting your errors, but that's the first thing that comes to mind. Please post the entire error if this doesn't help.

The reason for that is your `Setting` class inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`, calling `super` first calls parent's `initialize` method, this way you add functionality to the method (extend it). Without `super` you *override* it, meaning you replace everything it does by default (like for example connecting to the database, validating)  by your code.

Comment: Sorry about that. Added the full error. adding 'super' seems to solve it. Any reason why that is so?

Comment: @ali Because overriding initialize is not recommended-it's not your base class, and you bypassed all of Rails' initialization.

Answer (score 2):

Do not override `initialize` method on `ActiveRecord::Base`. Use `after_initialize` callback instead. Reference possibly with your problem http://blog.dalethatcher.com/2008/03/rails-dont-override-initialize-on.html